# bokeh not executing as it should due to different column lengths

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

```
#Plotting flower species

#Importing libraries
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
from bokeh.models import Range1d, PanTool, ResetTool, HoverTool

#Define the output file path
output_file("iris.html")

#Create the figure object
f = figure()

#Style the tools
f.tools = [PanTool(), ResetTool()]
f.add_tools(HoverTool())
f.toolbar_location = 'above'
f.toolbar.logo = None

#Style the plot area
f.plot_width = 1100
f.plot_height = 650
f.background_fill_color = "olive"
f.background_fill_alpha = 0.3

#Style the title
f.title.text = "Iris Morphology"
f.title.text_color = "olive"
f.title.text_font = "Agency FB"
f.title.text_font_size = "25px"
f.title.align = "center"

#Style the axes
f.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = "blue"
f.yaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
f.xaxis.visible = True
f.xaxis.minor_tick_in = -6
f.xaxis.axis_label = "Petal Length"
f.yaxis.axis_label = "Petal Width"
f.axis.axis_label_text_color = "blue"
f.axis.major_label_text_color = "orange"

#Axes geometry
f.x_range = Range1d(start=0, end=10)
f.y_range = Range1d(start=0, end=5)
f.xaxis.bounds = (2,6)
f.xaxis[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 2
f.yaxis[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 2
f.yaxis[0].ticker.num_minor_ticks = 10

#Style the grid
f.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
f.ygrid.grid_line_alpha = 0.6
f.grid.grid_line_dash = [5,3]

colormap = {'setosa':'red', 'versicolor':'green', 'virginica':'blue'}
flowers['color'] = [colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]

#adding glyphs
f.circle(x=flowers["petal_length"][flowers["species"]=="setosa"], 
y=flowers["petal_width"][flowers["species"]=="setosa"], 
size=flowers['sepal_width'][flowers["species"]=="setosa"]*4,
fill_alpha=0.2,color=flowers['color'][flowers["species"]=="setosa"],line_dash=[5,3],legend_label='Setosa')

f.circle(x=flowers["petal_length"][flowers["species"]=="versicolor"], 
y=flowers["petal_width"][flowers["species"]=="versicolor"],
size=flowers['sepal_width'][flowers["species"]=="versicolor"]*4,
fill_alpha=0.2,color=flowers['color'][flowers["species"]=="versicolor"],line_dash=[5,3],legend_label='Versicolor')

f.circle(x=flowers["petal_length"][flowers["species"]=="virginica"], 
y=flowers["petal_width"][flowers["species"]=="virginica"],
size=flowers['sepal_width'][flowers["species"]=="virginica"]*4,
fill_alpha=0.2,color=flowers['color'][flowers["species"]=="virginica"],line_dash=[5,3],legend_label='Virginica')

#Save and show the figure
show(f)
```

***BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('fill_color', 50), ('hatch_color', 50), ('line_color', 50), ('line_dash', 2), ('size', 50), ('x', 50), ('y', 50)
BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('fill_color', 50), ('hatch_color', 50), ('line_color', 50), ('line_dash', 2), ('size', 50), ('x', 50), ('y', 50)
BokehUserWarning: ColumnDataSource's columns must be of the same length. Current lengths: ('fill_color', 50), ('hatch_color', 50), ('line_color', 50), ('line_dash', 2), ('size', 50), ('x', 50), ('y', 50)***

my column lengths are all the same and cant figure out why it isnt working

Comment: It looks like this `line_dash=[5,3]` part is the problem. This adds a list with the length of two, all other lists have 50 elements. Try to reomve this and run your code again. If this solves your problem you can try to set an appropriate value.

Comment: that partially worked, as now the hovering tools do not work at all and its just a static image

Comment: Remove them, too. A few tools are activated by default. See if they are working. This [documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html) is a good start to read about tools.